# Dual booting with two drives

Tags: linux, dual-boot, boot-loader

So I need to install a microsoft product on one of my drives today sadly. My current setup is so that I have a SSD which has Linux on it. And a 1 TB HDD which just extends my Videos and Documents folder from the SSD.

If I were to decrease the ext4 partition size on that HDD and install windows on on the remainder, would it still affect my bootloader, that resides on the SSD (Mess up my bootloader so that I can not boot to Linux anymore)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I were to decrease the ext4 partition size on that HDD and install windows on on the remainder, would it still affect my bootloader, that resides on the SSD (Mess up my bootloader so that I can not boot to Linux anymore)?

No, it would not affect the bootloader or anything else on the other disk, unless a mistake is made and the new installation goes on the wrong disk.

If you are not *exactly* sure what kind of automated things the OS installer will do behind your back and/or you want to be as safe as possible, I suggest disconnecting the disk on which you do *not* want to install during the installation. Then plug it back in afterwards and leave it plugged in.